# For $x^2-3y^2=1$ over integers more than $1$, can $\frac{y+1}2$ be square number?

Tags: diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

> For $x^2-3y^2=1$ over integers more than 1, can $\frac{y+1}2$ be square number?

I know that $x^2-3y^2=1$ is one of pell's equation, so I know its general solution. But I know nothing about its properties, and I can't proceed my proof. How should I approach this question?

Comment: Google is your friend.. eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation

Comment: @unseen_rider How does this help to answer the question ?

Comment: OP mentioned: "But I know nothing about its properties". I'm making the point that it doesn't hurt for them to do some researching / searching. They also haven't mentioned what they have done & tried.

Comment: According to my calculations, the first $5\cdot 10^4$ convergents do not satisfy the given condition, so there should be no such solution. To prove that rigorously we have to solve $$x^2=12z^4 - 12 z^2 + 4$$ completely and show that there is no integer solution with $z>1$. Maybe, someone can do this.

Comment: @Peter.- I have did what you say but an obstinate one tells me that $y$ must fulfill a single condition and does not understand reasons why $y$ is forced to fulfill two conditions that precisely lead to your conclusion. And he is seconded in his false "rigor" by other people.

Comment: if $x^2-3y^2=1$ and $x$ is even, then $x-1$ is a square; if $x^2-3y^2=1$ and $x$ is odd, then $\frac{x+1}2$ is a square

Comment: Are you sure the question is about $\frac{y+1}2$ and not $\frac{x+1}2$?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Actually, I'm trying to prove that there is no solution 3x^4-3x^2+1=y^2 over integer more than 1 as you said. I could get (2y)^2-3*(2x^2-1)^2=1 by transforming it, so now I have to solve the question that I posted here.

Comment: Wow I just solved this very equation a few days ago (I was considering the problem $y^2 = x^3 + 1$, which can be reduced to solving this). I will write up the solution tomorrow when I have time. It is not short but entirely elementary.

Comment: [Paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL17/Alekseyev/alekseyev3.html) describe solving biquadratic equation as finite set Thue equations.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is equivalent to $y = 2z^2 - 1$ for some $z$.

Recall that all solutions to this Pell equation are parametrized by $x+y\sqrt 3 = (2 + \sqrt 3)^n$. Looking modulo 2, we see that we must have $n = 2k+1$ for some $k$. Denoting $a + b \sqrt 3 = (2 + \sqrt 3 )^k$, we see that $x + y\sqrt 3 = (a^2 + 3b^2 + 2ab \sqrt 3 )(2 + \sqrt 3)$, so we need to solve the equation

$2z^2 - 1 = a^2 + 3b^2 + 4ab$, where we have $a^2 - 3b^2 = 1$. Substituting this, we get $2z^2 - 1 = 2a^2 + 4ab - 1$, that is $z^2 = a(a+2b)$.

$\gcd(a, a+2b) = \gcd(a,2)$, so we split into cases.

**Case 1** $\gcd(a,2)=1$. In this case $a$ must be square, so it is sufficient to solve the equation $a^4 - 3b^2 = 1$. We will return to this later.

**Case 2** $\gcd(a,2)=2$. Then $a+2b = 2m^2$ for some $m$. Substituting this we get $(2m^2 - 2b)^2 - 3b^2 = b^2 - 8m^2b + 4m^4 = 1$ or

$b^2 - 8m^2b + (4m^4 - 1) = 0$

This is a quadratic equation in $b$, so in order for it to have integer solutions, the discriminant must be a square, that is $12m^4 + 1 = \ell^2$ for some $\ell$.

$\ell^2 - 3(2m^2)^2 = 1$, so $\ell + 2m^2 \sqrt 3 = (2 + \sqrt 3)^2t$ (we know that it is an even power because modulo 2). Denoting $c + d \sqrt 3 = (2 + \sqrt 3)^t$ we get $\ell^2 = cd$, so in particular $c$ is a square, and once again we find that it is sufficient to solve the equation $a^4 - 3b^2 = 1$.

---

Very cool lemma: Defining $x_n + y_n \sqrt d = (x_1 + y_1 \sqrt d)^n$, where $x_1 + y_1 \sqrt d$ is a solution to the Pell equation for $d$, we always have that $x_{4k}$ is never a square.

Proof: You can easily check that $x_{4k} = 8x_k^4 - 8x_k^2 + 1$, so it suffices to prove that the equation $y^2 = 8x^4 - 8x^2 + 1$ has no solutions.

$y^2 - 2(2x^2 - 1)^2 = -1$, and by the same technique as before (defining $a + b\sqrt 2 = (1 + \sqrt 2)^k$ we find that $2x^2 - 1 = a^2 + 2b^2 + 2ab$ where $a^2 - 2b^2 = +- 1$. We divide into cases:

**Case 1**: $a^2 - 2b^2 = 1$. We then get $2x^2 - 1 = 2a^2 + 2ab - 1$, that is $x^2 = a(a+b)$. In particular, $a$ is a square so we get the equation $a^4 - 2b^2 = 1$. This is well known to have only trivial solutions, my favorite proof moving things over and squaring we get $(\frac{a^4 + 1}{2})^2 - a^4 = b^4$ which is a Pythagorean triple containing two squares, and that is known since Fermat to have only trivial solutions.

**Case 2**: $a^2 - 2b^2 = -1$. We then get $2x^2 - 1 = 4b^2 + 2ab -1$, that is $x^2 = b(a+2b)$. In particular, $a+2b$ is a square (trying to use $b$ here is a trap: the equation $y^2 - 2x^4 = -1$ is notoriously hard and has the solution $y=239, x=13$). Setting $a = k^2 - 2b$ and substituting we get

$k^4 - 4bk^2 + 4b^2 - 2b^2 = -1$

$2b^2 - 4bk^2 + (k^4 + 1)$. This is a quadratic in $b$, so the discriminant must be a square, that is $2(k^4 - 1)$ is a square, or $k^4 - 1$ is twice a square, but we have just solved that.

So the lemma is proved.

---

Now in our case we have $x_n + y_n \sqrt 3 = (2 + \sqrt 3)^n$, and we want to show that $x_n$ is not a square for $n > 0$. From the lemma we just proved, we know that $n$ is not divisible by 4. Notice that if $x_n = k^2$ is even, then $x_n^2$ is divisible by 8 and we get $-3y_n^2 \equiv 1 \mod 8$ which is impossible. Therefore $x_n$ is odd and so $n$ must be even, so $n = 4\ell + 2$. However, let's look at $(2 + \sqrt 3)^n$ modulo 4.

$(2 + \sqrt 3)^2 = 7 + 4\sqrt 3 \equiv -1 \mod 8$ and so $(2 + \sqrt 3)^{4\ell + 2} \equiv (-1)^{2\ell + 1} = -1 \mod 4$, but squares are never $-1 \mod 4$, which is a contradiction.

QED

---

In fact, a more general result is true: If $x^4 - Dy^2 = 1$, then $x^2 + y \sqrt D$ is either the first or the second smallest solution to the relevant Pell equation, and the only time both of them are squares is $D = 1785$. This was proved by J.H.E. Cohn (once I recall the paper I will add it in the comments) using a rather heavy result of Ljunggren and some ingenious computations with Jacobi symbols.

Answer (score 0):

ADDED: kind of neat, the numbers of interest factor as the product of two sequences, both staisfy $$ w_{n+2} = 4 w_{n+1} - w_n \; , \; $$
one sequence begins $ 2, 7, 26, 97..$ and the other starts $1, 4, 15, 56, ...$ It is therefore **possible** this could be finished without elliptic curves. ADDED EXTRA: Alright, worth investigating, the two sequences are precisely the pairs of solutions to $u^2 - 3 v^2 = 1,$ as in $2^2 - 3 \cdot 1^2 = 1 \;, \; \; $  $7^2 - 3 \cdot 4^2 = 1 \;, \; \; $ $26^2 - 3 \cdot 15^2 = 1 \;, \; \; $    $97^2 - 3 \cdot 56^2 = 1 \;, \; \; $  There is, though,  a bit of an index shift: we are not using $15 \cdot 26,$ we are using $15 \cdot 7.$

```
    1:..................... 1 = 1 * 1
1 = 1 * 1

    2 :  ...................8 = 4 * 2
8 = 4 * 2

    3  y_n:  209  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 105 = 3 5  7
105 =  15 *  7    gcd 1

    4  y_n:  2911  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 1456 = 2^4 7  13
1456 =  56 *  26    gcd 2

    5  y_n:  40545  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 20273 = 11 19  97
20273 =  209 *  97    gcd 1

    6  y_n:  564719  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 282360 = 2^3 3 5 13  181
282360 =  780 *  362    gcd 2

    7  y_n:  7865521  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 3932761 = 7 41 71  193
3932761 =  2911 *  1351    gcd 1

    8  y_n:  109552575  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 54776288 = 2^5 7 97  2521
54776288 =  10864 *  5042    gcd 2

    9  y_n:  1525870529  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 762935265 = 3^2 5 17 31 53  607
762935265 =  40545 *  18817    gcd 1

   10  y_n:  21252634831  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 10626317416 = 2^3 11 13 19 37 73  181
10626317416 =  151316 *  70226    gcd 2

   11  y_n:  296011017105  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 148005508553 = 7 23 43 571  37441
148005508553 =  564719 *  262087    gcd 1

   12  y_n:  4122901604639  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 2061450802320 = 2^4 3 5 7 13 193  489061
2061450802320 =  2107560 *  978122    gcd 2

   13  y_n:  57424611447841  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 28712305723921 = 97 2131 3691  37633
28712305723921 =  7865521 *  3650401    gcd 1

   14  y_n:  799821658665135  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 399910829332568 = 2^3 41 71 2521  6811741
399910829332568 =  29354524 *  13623482    gcd 2

   15  y_n:  11140078609864049  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 5570039304932025 = 3 5^2 7^2 11 19 29 241 337  3079
5570039304932025 =  109552575 *  50843527    gcd 1
```

==============

ORIGINAL

Just curious. Mordell's book points out that there are just finitely many integer solutions to $$ u^2 = a v^4 + b v^2 + c,  $$
for example pages 236, 257, 268.  The suitable values $y_n,$ the odd ones, satisfy
$$   y_{n+2} = 14 y_{n+1} - y_n $$
beginning with $y_1 = 1$ and $y_2 = 15$ then $y_3 = 209.$

```
    3  y_n:  209  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 105 = 3 5  7
    4  y_n:  2911  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 1456 = 2^4 7  13
    5  y_n:  40545  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 20273 = 11 19  97
    6  y_n:  564719  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 282360 = 2^3 3 5 13  181
    7  y_n:  7865521  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 3932761 = 7 41 71  193
    8  y_n:  109552575  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 54776288 = 2^5 7 97  2521
    9  y_n:  1525870529  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 762935265 = 3^2 5 17 31 53  607
   10  y_n:  21252634831  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 10626317416 = 2^3 11 13 19 37 73  181
   11  y_n:  296011017105  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 148005508553 = 7 23 43 571  37441
   12  y_n:  4122901604639  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 2061450802320 = 2^4 3 5 7 13 193  489061
   13  y_n:  57424611447841  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 28712305723921 = 97 2131 3691  37633
   14  y_n:  799821658665135  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 399910829332568 = 2^3 41 71 2521  6811741
   15  y_n:  11140078609864049  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 5570039304932025 = 3 5^2 7^2 11 19 29 241 337  3079
   16  y_n:  155161278879431551  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 77580639439715776 = 2^6 7 13 31 61 97 181 607  661
   17  y_n:  2161117825702177665  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 1080558912851088833 = 67 101 443 509  708158977
   18  y_n:  30100488280951055759  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 15050244140475527880 = 2^3 3^2 5 13 17 37 53 73  1321442641
   19  y_n:  419245718107612602961  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 209622859053806301481 = 7 193 110771 191861  7300801
   20  y_n:  5839339565225625385695  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 2919669782612812692848 = 2^4 7 11 19 181 37441  18405321661
   21  y_n:  81331508195051142796769  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 40665754097525571398385 = 3 5 41 71 79 97 2017 3361  17927599
   22  y_n:  1132801775165490373769071  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 566400887582745186884536 = 2^3 13 23 43 571 757 2521 10333  489061
   23  y_n:  15777893344121814089970225  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 7888946672060907044985113 = 7 47 56857 1542841  273349327681
   24  y_n:  219757705042539906885814079  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 109878852521269953442907040 = 2^5 3 5 7 13 97 193 277 3037 37633  4244329
   25  y_n:  3060829977251436882311426881  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 1530414988625718441155713441 = 11 19 31 499 607 1049 524899  1416317953
   26  y_n:  42631861976477576445474162255  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 21315930988238788222737081128 = 2^3 181 2131 3691 6811741  274757858101
   27  y_n:  593785237693434633354326844689  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 296892618846717316677163422345 = 3^3 5 7 17 53 103^2 46817 140453  4998431569
   28  y_n:  8270361465731607290515101663391  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 4135180732865803645257550831696 = 2^4 7^2 13 37 41 71 73 109 337 1297 2521 3079  139537
   29  y_n:  115191275282549067433857096442785  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 57595637641274533716928548221393 = 59 97 521 2609 4417729  cdot mbox{BIG} 
   30  y_n:  1604407492489955336783484248535599  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 802203746244977668391742124267800 = 2^3 3 5^2 11 13 19 29 61 181 241 349 661 6961  3971200609
   31  y_n:  22346513619576825647534922383055601  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 11173256809788412823767461191527801 = 7 193 1201 2543 8059 37139 37441 203857  1185361
   32  y_n:  311246783181585603728705429114242815  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 155623391590792801864352714557121408 = 2^7 7 31 97 373 607  cdot mbox{BIG} 
   33  y_n:  4335108450922621626554341085216343809  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 2167554225461310813277170542608171905 = 3 5 23 43 127 571 391249 652081  cdot mbox{BIG} 
   34  y_n:  60380271529735117168032069763914570511  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 30190135764867558584016034881957285256 = 2^3 13 67 101 443 509 150217 489061 1959673  1321442641
   35  y_n:  840988692965369018725894635609587643345  (y_n + 1) / 2 : 420494346482684509362947317804793821673 = 7 11 19 41 71 139 3943 66499 5352481  cdot mbox{BIG}
```

Comment: The one sequence is $\dfrac{(2+\sqrt3)^n+(2-\sqrt3)^n}2$ and the other is$\dfrac{(2+\sqrt3)^{n+1}-(2-\sqrt3)^{n+1}}{2\sqrt3}$; from that, it's easy to show that the $2n+1^{th}$ term of the second sequence plus $1$, then divided by $2$, is the product of the $n^{th}$ term of the first sequence and the $n+1^{th}$ term of the second sequence

Comment: @J.W.Tanner good. The type of thing that might finish the original problem is proving that the gcd of the two sequence elements is always 1 or 2, so getting the product equal to a square demands either both squares or both doubles of squares. That might be hard, it might be really trivial.

Comment: Call the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$.  We have $a_n^2-3b_n^2=1$, so $\gcd(a_n,b_n)=1$.  Furthermore, $b_{n+1}=a_n+2b_n$.  So if $d|a_n$ and $d|b_{n+1}$ then $d|2b_n$, but since $\gcd(a_n,b_n)=1$, that means $d|2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner be careful about the index shift; one of the factorings is 1456 =  56 *  26 where both factors are even... one of the earliest is 8 = 4 * 2

Comment: I should have said the other sequence is $\dfrac{(2+\sqrt3)^n-(2-\sqrt3)^n}{2\sqrt3}$  (is that what your last comment means?)

Comment: Can you prove there are no squares or doubles of squares in the sequences?

Comment: Besides $1$, $2$,  and $4$?

Comment: I think It is harder than it seems to be... but I'm trying to prove it

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2-3y^2=1\implies y^2=\frac{x^2-1}{3}\implies \frac{x-1}{p}\cdot\frac{x+1}{q}\quad\text{where}\quad p,q\quad \text{ divides }\quad 3$$

It is easy to see the solutions of $p=1,q=3\text{ and }x=1\lor x=2$ but perhaps there are other values of x divisible by these factors and, it happens there are.

For $x-1$, x can be any integers and, $x+1$ can be any multiple of $3$ such as $3,6,9$ but the result, divided by 3 must be a perfect square and these get rarer with altitude. Here is a sample of infinite $(x,y)$ solutions. Only positive integers are shown for simplicity but negatives apply as well.

$$(x,y)\in\{(1,0),(2,1),(7,4),(26,15),(97,56),(362,209), \cdots\}$$
This gives no definition of the set. A search is still required and although a solution for $x$ would be faster it alone yields just few insights into the values of $y$ that yield integers.

$$x^2-3y^2=1\implies x^2={3y^2+1}$$
There is a brighter side though, in that both $x$ and $y$ values are known sequences in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Sequence [A001075](http://oeis.org/A001075)
shows $x\in\{ 1, 2, 7, 26, 97, 362, \cdots\}$

Sequence [A001353](http://oeis.org/A001353)
shows $y\in\{ 0, 1, 4, 15, 56, 209, \cdots\}$

These sequences often come with several formulas for their generation and perhaps one of them may meet your needs in generating the $n^{th}$ pair directly.